# Different permission descriptions in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I have two TFS 2017 servers, both running version 15.112.26301.0 (Tfs2017.Update1).

On one server the collection was created by TFS 2017 while the other server runs a collection upgraded from TFS 2012.

When I view the Security settings for a Team Project I get different permission descriptions between the two servers.

The new collection has the permissions "Delete work items in this project" and "Permanently delete work items in this project" while the upgraded collection has "Delete and restore work items" and "Permanently delete work items". This applies to all Team Projects whether they were created when the collection has running TFS 2012 or after the upgrade to 2017.

I hope that the permissions give the users the same possibilities but the difference annoys me.

Am I missing something or is this expected for a new versus an upgraded collection?

Comment: Have you completely configured features after the upgrade?https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade, and what about the new collections in the upgraded TFS? you can try to create a new collection in the upgraded TFS, then create a  new team project in the new collection to check if the permissions have the same issue.

Comment: The features were configured after the upgrade. I double-checked the installations and the "new" collection was actually created on TFS 2015 and it is the collection upgraded from 2015 that has the wrong texts. I created a new collection on the same server and it shows the correct texts when I compare them with VSTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design, the permission items "**Delete work items in this project**" and "**Permanently delete work items in this project**" only appear on **TFS 2015**. So, the collection must be upgraded from TFS 2015.

Since TFS 2017 (including the latest VSTS) the permission items changed to "**Delete and restore work items**" and "**Permanently delete work items**".

So when you install a new TFS 2017 or create a new collection on the existing TFS 2017, it will display the new items, but for the migrated/moved collections from TFS 2015, they will keep the previous permission items.

Comment: Both my servers are on-premise. I just made the VSTS comparison as I thought it should be the same. So I have a server that says "Delete work items in this project" and "Permanently delete work items in this project" but if I make a new collection on the server the text in the new collection is "Delete and restore work items" and "Permanently delete work items". The latter is what the other on-premise server (the one with the collection upgraded from TFS 2012) has said all along. I will try to make a new collection on the server and compare it to the upgraded 2012 collection.

Comment: I have now created a new collection on the server with the upgraded 2012 collection. Both collections have the VSTS text, namely "Delete and restore work items" and "Permanently delete work items". Only on the server where the collection is upgraded from 2015 do I have the on-premise texts you describe above and only in that collection. If I make a new collection on that server I also get the VSTS texts. So I have four on-premise collections where three of them display VSTS texts and one does not. All across two servers running the same TFS version. I don't get it.

Comment: @MichaelHarmsen Sorry for the confusion, I checked this issue again on TFS 2012, TFS 2013, TFS 2015 , TFS 2017 and the latest VSTS, then get the point, I have updated the answer, please see it for details.

Comment: Thanks Andy. While it isn't pretty is does explain the difference in my collections.